# Java: weak pre condition and strong post condition, how to?

Tags: java, preconditions, post-conditions

I'm having a really hard time in understanding how pre-conditions and post-conditions must work, without violate the Substitution Principle. So let's assume that we have a class `Rectangle` and `Square`—how to relate them? Which one must be the subclass?

So I undertand that the pre-conditions of a `Subtype` can be weaker, that means that we can take a major 'set' of things in out subclass, on the other hand the post-condition can be stronger so we can return a minor 'set' of things. How can I appply these rules in my example?

I read that the baseclass must 'do' less than the subclass, so I think that `Square` must be our baseclass and `Rectangle` the subclass. Thus the pre-condition in `Square` must be assert that `height == width`, but what about the post-conditions and the pre-conditions in `Rectangle`?

Comment: I would say both `Square` and `Rectangle` are `subclasses` of `Shape`

Comment: assume that i want to set one of the fist two as subclass of the other

Comment: hmm, so every `Square` is a `Rectangle` --> `Rectangle` is a superClass of `Square`

Comment: so in that case square must have stronger pre-condition in order to check heigth == width, so it violates the SP principles

Comment: yes, condition for rectangle is (it has height and width) and condition for square is (it has height and width **AND** height==width)

Comment: ok so Rectangle is the superclass means that Square has stronger pre-conditions, because height and width in Rectangle can be any integer major than zero but in Square they can be only equal to each other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93479/discussion-between-francesco-and-nafas).

Comment: actually this is the typical example in which inheritance falls short: you cannot really relate them in code as you do in real world. It's somewhere in the Clean Code video series from Uncle Bob (I do not remember exactly which one)

Comment: I have a similar question here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/358757/how-to-losen-input-contracts-by-inheritance I even used the same square and rectangle example somewhere else. Interesting how hard LSP is in practice.

Comment: I think the point by LSP that if you inherit the Square from the Rectangle class, then you will get unexpected errors by using a Square instance in a code written for a Rectangle instance. The Square has a constraint on width and hight so by setting those in your code you can get unexpected errors if they do not equal. Since the squares pass the type check for Rectangle, using LSP is the only way to ensure that the code won't break unexpectedly. Thus Rectangle can't be a base class of the Square class, because it would violate LSP. You need a different model instead.

Answer (score 2):

A general way to find out super and subclasses, you basically need to answer this question:

> Is every X a Y?

In you case you need to say these two things:

- Is every `Rectangle` a `Square`? **No.**
- Is every `Square` a `Rectangle`? **Yes.**

Thus `Square` is a `Rectangle`. Then the condition for becoming `Square` is:

- If it's a rectangle; *and*
- the height equals the width.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand every square is a rectangle but every rectangle is not a square.

Condition you need for rectangle is its has 4 size not less not more and any three angles are 90 degrees.

In code they should be 2 different classes. I haven't defined polygon class but you get the concept of it.

Eg :

```
public class Quadrilateral extends Polygon {
    ...
}
```

Next :

```
public class Rectangle extends Quadrilateral {
    private double length;
    private double breadth;

   public Rectangle (double len, double brd ) {...}

}
```

Then square :

```
public class Square extends Rectangle {
    private double side;
    public Square (double sideLength) {
         super(sideLength, sideLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, ok i know geometry. But you don't answer the question that is about how to relate the two classes

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's the otherway round. Square is a SubClass of Rectangle. Why? Every Square 'is a' Rectangle, but not every Rectangle 'is a' Square.

You can extend this inheritance relation further, every GeometricShape is an Object, every Polygon is a GeometricShape, every Quadrangle is a Polygon, every Rectangle is a Quadrangle, etc. The further you go down the inheritance hierarchy, the more constraints are added, making the subclasses more special, than the parent classes.

What is a contraint of a Rectangle? Every corner has a rectangular agle (90°), what is the the constraint of a Square? Its a rectangle (90°) with every edge being of the same length.

Comment: so in that case square must have stronger pre-condition in order to check heigth == width, so it violates the SP principles

Comment: no, SP is not violated, whenever a Rectangle is needed, you can use a Square, but not the other way round. You can substitute any Rectangle (Baseclass) with a Square (SubClass). But when a Square is required (stronger pre condition), you can not substitute it with Rectangle (unless it's a Square).

Comment: Ok, so Square has stronger pre-condition that is a violation of the SP principles. If S is a subclass of B, then S must have the same or weaker pre-condition of B

Answer (score 0):

#### Subtyping

A subclass, or child class, is always a specialized type of the base class, or superclass.

Java uses the keyword `extends`, because the subclass actually *extends* the superclass, often adds functionality.

A square is a special, that is, *more specific* type of a rectangle. It is a rectangle, but with the additional property that the height equals the width.

---

#### Liskov Substitution Principle

*However*, the Substitution Principle – I'm guessing that you mean the Liskov Substitution Principle – states that anywhere where you would expect a certain class (in our case `Rectangle`), you should be able to use a subtype of that class (in our case `Square`), without breaking the functionality or logic. If you're not, the design violates the Liskov Subtitution Principle.

I can give an example, but it is [already written in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584732/507738). Note that this answer uses the classes you mentioned.

So, to summarize, it sounds logical that a square is a specialized type of a rectangle, but according to the Liskov Substitution Principle, it is bad abstraction.

So yes, declaring `Square` as subclass of `Rectangle` **fails** the Liskov Substitution Principle.

*Note that they also wrote [a Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) about it. It's a very common problem.*

Answer (score 0):

- Rectangle is subclass of Square. Reason being, rectangle is a weaker
  form of square: it has weaker preconditions.
- Square preconditions:
  four sides, all adjoining at 90 degree, all sides equals.
- Rectangle
  has only first two preconditions. Will these two behave same for
  client code? Yes.
- Square: getArea() {return side*side}
- Rectangle:

  - getArea() {return l * w} << same interface Square constructor:
- Square(int side) Rectangle constructor 1:
- Rectangle(int side){l = side; w = side;} << same interface as square
- Rectangle constructor 2:

  - Rectangle(int l, int w){this.l = s; this.w = w}  << new addition
- Why is rectangle allowed to have an extra
  constructor? Because it extends square, and therefore can add
  functionality, but cannot restrain functionality of superclass.